# How do I run WEBrick as an upstart job?

Tags: linux, ruby, ruby-on-rails, upstart

I need to get [WEBrick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEBrick) (basically a Rails web server) to work using upstart, but cannot figure out what should I write in script.

The following gives me an error:

```
chdir /rails-app

exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' myuser -- rails server -e production

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]
```

(the error is `rails: 1: exec: rails: not found`)

Ruby is installed via `rvm`, so probably I should try something like :

```
exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' myuser -- /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/bundle exec rails server -e production
```

But this doesn't work too (`/usr/bin/env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory`).

How do I run WEBrick as an upstart job?